# Cakephp 3, how to show joined table

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i have my table 
 `accounts (
  id int(10)
  username
  password 
)`

and members table 
`members (
  id
  account_id
  first_name
  last_name
  e_mail
  address
  book_count
)` 
i have to show both of the tables in one view with INNER join, how it can be possible?

Comment: Please be a little more specific about what the actual technical problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Read [HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) will solve your problem.

You should follow [Cake tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) to know more about cakephp

If you don't use associations you can do normally with join function

```
$accounts->join([
    'table' => 'members',
    'alias' => 'mem',
    'type' => 'INNER', //LEFT, RIGHT...
    'conditions' => 'mem.account_id = accounts.id',
])->...
```